# Multi threading concerns on asp.net core async continuations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have read that asp.net core doesn't have a sync context and as such any async method continuation will be executed in a threadpool context.

Imagine you have a controller's http action async method that awaits some other method. Does that mean that any code bellow the `await` is expected to run in a different thread than the code until the `await`? I mean, does that mean that if this method shares any object with other methods like this one, I should be concerned about shared state in a, apparently, multi threaded code inside this very method (like using mutex on accessing shared stated, etc)?

Comment: Shared between what? It doesn't make sens as http is stateless and instance of controller is created per request

Comment: @Selvin does that really matter to the question? Imagine I have a static object that is shared among those methods.

Comment: Yes it does. Because nothing is normally shared between requests. A new Controller instance is created to serve each request. To share state you'd have to use cache or session storage. `Imagine I have a static object` don't

Comment: *Imagine I have a static objec* I can't ... static object in controller is terrible idea ...

Comment: First of all, static data won't work if you have even a moderate web site that uses two or more servers eg for load balancing or for blue/green deployments. That means it won't work in cloud environments. Second, the type of data matters. Is it lookup data? It goes to a cache. Is it user-specific data? It may go to session storage, or it may move between client and server as cookies, form fields etc

Comment: Guys I know that. I only asked you to assume that to help me understand what is going on in that particular case. Ie., Should I assume that continuations in an asp.net core environment are expected to execute in a different thread and as such it could potentially fall into the MT problems around shared state?

Comment: @underthevoid each request is served by a different thread. It's not continuations that will cause conflicts, it's multiple request threads trying to modify the same state at the same time. Inside a single request it it doesn't matter that continuations run on different threads, since only one thread will process a request at any time. That's why you can access *instance* fields without conflicts. If you use static fields though, conflicts are guaranteed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh, so in a given request scenario only 1 TP thread is given to execute the entire request code? So in a continuation inside a controller's method I am guaranteed that will be executed in the same thread that awaited the continuation call? Isnt that the same as having a sybc context?

Comment: No. The thread will be different, but since only one thread accesses the fields at a time, it doesn't matter. That's why you can use an injected DbContext with async actions - only one thread touches it at a time

Comment: @underthevoid what are you trying to do? The fact all doc examples use `async` actions should make it clear it's safe to use asynchronous methods. Statics? Bad idea. Thread-local storage? Bad idea, because the thread will work on a different request

Comment: Ohh got it! Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos l. That really helped me visualize the whole thing. Feel free to write an answer that I will accept.

Comment: About your second question: Im just trying to understand what is happening under the cover here

Answer (score 8):

> I have read that asp.net core doesn't have a sync context and as such any async method continuation will be executed in a threadpool context.

This is true.

> Does that mean that any code bellow the await is expected to run in a different thread than the code until the await?

It might. It will run on any thread pool thread, which may or may not be the same thread that was running the code before the `await`.

Note: ASP.NET pre-Core *had the same behavior*. The synchronization context used by pre-Core ASP.NET did *not* guarantee staying on the same thread. The thread could be any thread pool thread, just like in Core; the context just handled things like ensuring `HttpContext.Current` refers to the correct object (this static property no longer exists in Core).

> I mean, does that mean that if this method shares any object with other methods like this one, I should be concerned about shared state in a, apparently, multi threaded code inside this very method

Asynchronous code is *sequential* (not "synchronous"), so the standard pattern of "call this method, `await` the result; call the next method, `await` the result" does not have to worry about multithreading within the same method. The thread may change throughout the method, but the `await`s serialize the code execution.

Now, if the code does something like `Task.WhenAll` (or `Task.WhenAny`), then that's a clue that you need to look deeper. In that case, the code *is* doing concurrency, and each of those tasks *may* be running multithreaded on different threads. I cover this in the "Beware Implicit Parallelism" section in my [blog post on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).

> like using mutex

Mutex - with its synchronous-only API and thread-affine state - is incorrect to use with *any* asynchronous code. Again, this was true in ASP.NET pre-Core as well.